# How to add a usercontrol dynamically without using <%@ register %> or <%@ Reference %>?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have some usercontrol which gets loaded dynamicaly. I know how to add these usercontrols dynamically. The problem is, which usercontrol are to be added is decided only at runtime. So I cannot use <%@ register %> or <%@ Reference %> on the '.aspx' page.

How to access the usercontrols without using these directives?

Answer (score 2):

You can register all of your user controls within your `web.config` eliminating the need to register them at page level -- or needing to make a decision on which ones to register (at page level).  e.g.

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="myControl" src="~/Controls/uc.ascx" tagName="header"/>
 </controls>
</pages>
```

Check out this post by Scott Gu for additional help [Tip/Trick Registering User Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx)

Comment: It does not work. Still getting this error.  The type or namespace name 'UsercontrolName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you mean, in Page_Load method:

var ctrl = LoadControl("yourcontrol.ascx");
Controls.Add(ctrl);

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply resister all usercontrols in your page (or even better in your web.config), and then this will not be an issue.

Comment: As I said, I only know which user control to be added at runtime. I don't want to register all the usercontrol to page.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of where you register the control, it won't be automatically loaded on the page if you don't put a tag for it on the page.

To load the user control dynamically from code, you **use the LoadControl method**:

```
void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Instantiate the UserControl object
    MyControl myControl1 =
        (MyControl)LoadControl("TempControl_Samples1.ascx.cs");
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myControl1);
}
```

Knowing that this is the method to use, you will be able to find plenty of examples. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is one place to start.

Comment: The example that you have given will work only when the programmer know which control to load. But in my case, which usercontrol to be added is decided at runtime. So I cannot use <%2 reference %>. Can i?

Comment: @syd: This will definitely work once you have resolved the issue of how to register the user controls in web.config.

Comment: I have already register the user control in web.config.                <add src="~/UserControls/Jobs/PagesAndJobs.ascx" tagName="PagesAndJobs" tagPrefix="ucPnJ" />. still getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put them into panel or multiview and display accordingly. But you also need to register it into webconfig.

Answer (score 0):

On the page's code-behind:

```
var ctrl = LoadControl("user.ascx");
this.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Comment: Why cant I get a strongly typed user control in my code behind file without registering it on my aspx page. Like: MyControl myUserControl = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/MessageControl.ascx");  I am unable to add its namespace to get its type. Why so ? Some SO examples suggest that it shouldn't be a problem.